# Write a regex to find data between the 6th and 12th character of a string

Tags: regex, validation, input

I have two text input fields in my application, on the first one the user will enter a string with the following format: `"L2018RU99999A"`.

On the second input field, I have to perform a validation to ensure that the data entered is equal to the characters between sixth and the twelfth of the first string, so in this case: `RU99999`. What kind of regex would be appropriate to solve this problem?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You may use positive lookbehind:

`(?<=.{5}).{7}`

- `.{7}` find seven characters ...
- `(?<=.{5})` ... which have five other characters before them

Comment: Someone upvoted and someone downvoted my answer. May I know what was the reason of downvote?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `substring()` or whatever equivalent in the programming language you use. If for whatever reason you need a regular expression, try `^.....(.......).$` (where `$1` is the string you're looking for)

Comment: `^.{5}(.{7}).{1}$` with quantifiers